# Django: Creating a unique identifier for a user based on request.META values

Tags: django, http, browser, django-forms, http-headers

I'm looking at creating an anonymous poll. However, I want to prevent users from voting twice. I was thinking of hashing some `request.META` values like so:

```
from hashlib import md5

request_id_keys = (
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE',
    'HTTP_CONNECTION',
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT',
    'REMOTE_ADDR',
)

request_id = md5('|'.join([request.META.get(k, '') for k in requst_id_keys])).hexdigest()
```

My questions:

1. Good idea? Bad idea? Why?
2. Are some of these keys redundant or just overkill? Why?
3. Are some of these easily changeable? For example, I'm considering removing `HTTP_USER_AGENT` because I know that's just a simple config change.
4. Know of a better way of accomplishing this semi-unique identifier that is flexible enough to handle people sharing IP's (NAT) but that a simple config change won't create a new hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of this params are fairly easy to change. Why not just use a cookie for that purpose? I guess something like [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/)

> evercookie is a javascript API available that produces extremely persistent cookies in a browser. Its goal is to identify a client even after they've removed standard cookies, Flash cookies (Local Shared Objects or LSOs), and others.

Comment: Awesome idea. +1 for evercookie.

Comment: All I did was go to Chrome Incognito mode and I appeared as a new user. I was hoping something more robust than that. Not to mention I feel kind of skeevy using some vulnerabilities to track users.

Comment: If it's an anonymous poll, you must accept that there will be users you cannot track, otherwise you'll end up being 'skeevy'.