# PHP - Block IPs for 24 hours

Tags: php, ip

I have a PHP file that I want to collect people's IP's then prevent the PHP file from continuing if their IP has run the file within the last 24 hours. I've tried with cookies, but it kept giving me "can't change header" errors. Plus, people could just clear their cookies. Basically, it keeps the IP's of everyone who runs the php file, then if they try to access it within 24 hours it does "echo "You can access this again in 24 hours" and doesn't run the whole file. Then they can do it again after 24 hours.

Comment: This is going to cause problems for users behind routers or NATs. Basically anyone inside a school or corporate network will be stymied by this strategy because the'll all appear to you as coming from the same public IP address.

Comment: [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: You will need to persist this information somewhere on the server, like a database for example.

Comment: IP restriction is not safer than cookies, because people can just connect through a proxy

Comment: @Michael - At least some of that could be mitigated by using [request headers to generate a semi-unique signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086371/django-creating-a-unique-identifier-for-a-user-based-on-request-meta-values), or using an [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) (shudder). Although nico's point is good.

Comment: Another approach could be to embargo any user without a cookie identifying them to your server from accessing the file (for 24 hours). Note, the flaw in the cookie argument is that the user could just open another browser to circumvent that protection. Why don't you just have people login so you know who they are?

Answer (score 2):

Every time the page is viewed check if the ip address is in a database table after removing entries that are over 24 hours old

```
// Purge records
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ip_table WHERE access_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)");

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM ip_table WHERE ip = '$ip'");
if($result){
  die("You can access this again in 24 hours");
} 
else {
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip_table (ip, access_date) VALUES ('$ip', NOW())");
}
```

However, this will block all users using a shared connection. It is better to require a login, then block access per user.

Comment: It isn't giving me any errors, but it's not updating the database

Comment: Ok, I got it to update to the database, but the  if($result) isn't working. It still performs even though my IP is in the database

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much easier for you to have a table that stores the last access time for each ip, with a structure like:

```
Access

 - id          - int
 - ip_addr     - int
 - last_access - datetime
```

you transform from IP address in `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` to an integer value with [`inet_pton()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php), and do a simple select in that DB table

Answer (score 1):

Approaches I can possibly see working more often than not:

### IP Banning

**Pros:**

- Will block all browsers with that IP address
- Fairly easy to setup

**Cons:**

- May get lots of false positives for people behind NATs, etc.
- User could move to another computer or otherwise change IP (proxy)

### Cookies

**Pros:**

- You have an identity for the browser that it's reporting
- Easy to setup and deploy

**Cons:**

- Very easy to defeat (delete the cookie)

### User login

**Pros:**

- You know which account is downloading and when
- Hard to circumvent *by account*

**Cons:**

- Could be easily circumvented if new accounts are easy to setup

---

Note, [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is what holds the IP address and other information about the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply track ip's with a date they accessed the php file, and update this date after 24 hours has passed if they try to re-access.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'] can be stored in a database, compared against
err s/SESSION/SERVER
(rewriting session crap over here, have session on the brain)
```

Update :-

Useful links

http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/07/03/how-to-block-ip-addresses-with-php/

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=67344